# Deleting an entity with a one to many relationship on two levels result in a foreign key exception

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Hi I am trying to delete an entity from that database with a one to many relationship on two levels. I am using entity framework 6.

This is may database diagram for the module:

[image]

This is my code:

```
public partial class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext()
        : base("name=DatabaseContext")
    {
    }
          public virtual DbSet<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<PropertyCategory> PropertyCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TemplateProperty> TemplateProperties { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<TemplateProperyCategory> TemplateProperyCategories { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Property>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TemplateProperties)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Property)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PropertyCategory>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TemplateProperyCategories)
        .WithRequired(e => e.PropertyCategory)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateProperyCategory>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TemplateProperties)
        .WithRequired(e => e.TemplateProperyCategory)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.TemplatePropertyCategoryId)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Template>()
        .HasMany(e => e.TemplateProperyCategories)
        .WithRequired(e => e.Template)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
    }
}


public class TemplateService : ITemplateService
{
    private readonly ITemplateUnitOfWork templateUnitOfWork;

    public TemplateService(ITemplateUnitOfWork templateUnitOfWork)
    {
        this.templateUnitOfWork = templateUnitOfWork;
    }

    public void Delete(TemplateDTO templateDTO)
    {
        var template = templateUnitOfWork.TemplateRepository.GetById(templateDTO.Id);
        templateUnitOfWork.TemplateRepository.Delete(template);
        templateUnitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class BaseUnitOfWork
{
    protected DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;

    public void SaveChanges()
    {

        bool saveFailed;
        do
        {
            saveFailed = false;
            try
            {
                DatabaseContext.SaveChanges();
                DatabaseContext.Dispose();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                saveFailed = true;
                ex.Entries.Single().Reload();
            }

        } while (saveFailed);
    }
}

public class TemplateUnitOfWork : BaseUnitOfWork, ITemplateUnitOfWork
{
    private IRepository<Template> templateRepository;

    public TemplateUnitOfWork(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
    {
        DatabaseContext = databaseContext;
    }


    public IRepository<Template> TemplateRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return templateRepository ?? (templateRepository =
                Injector.ResolverService.Resolve<IRepository<Template>>(DatabaseContext));
        }
    }

}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DatabaseContext DatabaseContext;

    protected readonly DbSet<T> DbSet;

    public Repository(DatabaseContext databaseContext)
    {
        DatabaseContext = databaseContext;
        DbSet = DatabaseContext.Set<T>();
        DatabaseContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
    }

    public void Delete(T entity)
    {
        DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry = DatabaseContext.Entry(entity);
        if (dbEntityEntry.State != EntityState.Deleted)
        {
            dbEntityEntry.State = EntityState.Deleted;
        }
        else
        {
            DbSet.Attach(entity);
            DbSet.Remove(entity);
        }
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
}
```

I want to be able to delete an element from the table Templates.When that happens I want it to delete all element related to it from TemplatePropertyCategories and all elements that have a relationship beetween TemplatePRoperties and TemplatePropertyCategories.

The databaseContext is generated usign Visual Studios Code First from database tools.

When I load the template entity it comes preloaded with both templatePropertyCategories and templateProperties.

I assumed that in order for this to work had to set WillCascadeDelete(true) for the free tables but that did nothing visible.

When I try to run this code I get this exception:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.TemplateProperties_dbo.Templates_TemplateId\". The conflict occurred in database \"TElectronics\", table \"dbo.TemplateProperyCategories\", column 'TemplateId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Changing the structure og the database is not an option.

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to configure **TemplateProperty** entity

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TemplateProperty>()
    .HasRequired(t => t.TemplatePropertyCategory)
    .WithMany(t => t.TemplateProperties)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.TemplatePropertyCategoryId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```